# How to configure two way SSL connection in Spring WS without using Spring boot and using separate Apache tomcat server?

Tags: java, security, spring-mvc, tomcat7, spring-ws

I need to send a soap request messages in a two way SSL connection security mechanism to a server and also process the Soap response from the server..**I am using Spring MVC along with Spring ws  which is configured entirely using annotations and requires to be configured in two way SSL connection for sending soap requests to the Server.How can I have two way  SSL connection in my Spring MVC web service application in order to send my soap messages to the sever over SSL?.**

Comment: If you have a certificate for your server, and access the web services over HTTPS, SSL/TLS will protect data in transit in both directions.

Comment: I am a beginner in web services and I have to figure out a way to configure my Spring Mvc Application for a two way SSL connection if you could help me with an example or sample code it would be great.

Comment: Are you asking about [Mutual Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_authentication)?

Comment: @hooknc I need to connect to a bank api with a soap request in a two way SSL connection from my Spring MVC application.

Comment: @brt which server you are using.

Comment: Maybe you ask about two-way authentication with client certificate?

Comment: @prashant Thorat I am using Tomcat 7 Server with Spring MVC

Comment: The Bank Api has given me choice to go with  SSL connection to connect to their api from my Spring MVC application.

Comment: that means your client project should run on ssl. i.e. https

Comment: @Prashant Thorat I do not want my entire Web application in https but only a part where I connect to the Bank Api

Answer (score 2):

I can guide you about all the required steps, but there are gaps. Please review my answer so I could provide you the right configuration links

***Two-Way SSL is a TLS connection with client certificate authentication***. It it not the same that signing soap request (certificate is used once to authenticate client in TLS (see [Two-way SSL clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725572/two-way-ssl-clarification)), and sign a soap is make a digital signature over the soap body and include it in the soap header)

You need a lot of things (please check)

- A server to manage TLS connection. You have selected tomcat. No problem, but in my opinion is simpler to put an apache with reverse proxy
- An SSL certificate, preferably issued by a trusted entity. If not, you can generate your own certificate, but needs extra configuration in next steps
- The public key of the SSL certificate (the x509 certificate) to configure the client truststore
- A client certificate to be authenticated in TLS connection
- openssl software in order to generate certificates
- I also recommend using this application (http://portecle.sourceforge.net/)to modify JKS keystores and not a hell

### ***Configure the server***

*1) Generate SSL certificate (server.crt and server.key)*

If you have one, go to 2). If not, follow http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 1024
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
cp server.key server.key.org
openssl rsa -in server.key.org -out server.key
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt
```

You'll get server.crt and server.key

*2) Convert to PKCS12  (server.pfx)*
Configuration will be simpler
If has provided you a certificate, also will give you a CACert.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out server.pfx -inkey server.key -in server.crt -certfile CACert.crt
```

*3) Generate a client certificate (client.p12)*
(extracted from https://gist.github.com/mtigas/952344)
    Create a Certificate Authority root 
     openssl genrsa -des3 -out ca.key 4096
     openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -key ca.key -out ca.crt

```
 Create the Client Key and CSR
 openssl genrsa -des3 -out client.key 4096
 openssl req -new -key client.key -out client.csr
 # self-signed
 openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in client.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 -out client.crt

 Convert Client Key to PKCS
 openssl pkcs12 -export -clcerts -in client.crt -inkey client.key -out client.p12
```

*4) Configure server truststore (truststore.jks)*

```
Open portecle
New KeyStore -> JKS
Import trusted certificate. Import client.crt and ca.crt
Save as truststore.jks
```

*5) Configure tomcat SSL with client auth*

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support
Similar  to Prashant Thorat answer

```
<Connector
    port="443"
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
    connectionTimeout="20000"
    redirectPort="8443"
    scheme="https" 
    secure="true" 
    SSLEnabled="true"
    sslProtocol="TLS"
    keystoreFile="server.pfx"
    keystorePass="thepassword" 
    keystoreType="PKCS12"
    truststoreFile="truststore.jks"
    truststorePass="thepassword"
    truststoreType="JKS"
    clientAuth="true">
```

### ***Configure the client***

*1) Create client trustore (client-truststore.jks)*
Open portecle, create a new JKS and include server certificate (server.crt) as trusted (

*2) Create client keystore (client-keystore.jks)*
Open portecle, create a new JKS and import a key/pair. Use client.p12 or client.crt and client.key. Import also ca.crt

*3) Configure spring*
I've never done WS spring, but with CXF. It's the same concept
You do not need to sign SOAP, you only need a TLS connection with client auth, so no soap configuration needed

Follow this tutorial
https://secinto.wordpress.com/2013/01/21/spring-and-webservices-how-to-use-ssltls-client-authentication/

the key is

```
private void setupTLSSpring() throws Exception {

 ProtocolSocketFactory authSSLProtocolSocketFactory = new AuthSSLProtocolSocketFactory(new URL(
     "file:%PATH_TO_KEYSTORE%/client-keystore.jks"), PASSWORD, new URL(
     "file:%PATH_TO_TRUSTSTORE%/client-truststore.jks"), PASSWORD);

 Protocol.registerProtocol("https", new Protocol("https", authSSLProtocolSocketFactory, 8410));
 }
```

### **EDITED**

If you use a Bank API, probably the bank provides the server with a trusted SSL certificate and a client certificate for authentication ¿It is not like this? 
in this case forget *'configure server'* section

In 'configure client' step 1, extract the public key from server SSL certificate and import into client-truststore.jks.

If some step is not suitable for your desired configuration, please detail it

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to share a `full tutorial` and `github project` link which is telling about two way ssl connection in spring.

**Full 2-way SSL Tutorial Link:**

[Everything You Ever Wanted to Know About SSL (but Were Afraid to Ask)](http://www.robinhowlett.com/blog/2016/01/05/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-ssl-but-were-afraid-to-ask/)

**Github Project Link:**

[boot two way ssl example](https://github.com/viniciusccarvalho/boot-two-way-ssl-example)

### UPDATE:

Actually, I have no same same code as requirement. But I got some links which are related to SSL. I am just sharing with you as helping hand.

1. [Making Authenticated Web Service Callouts Using Two-Way SSL](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Making_Authenticated_Web_Service_Callouts_Using_Two-Way_SSL)
2. [Accessing RESTful services configured with SSL using RestTemplate](http://aruld.info/accessing-restful-services-configured-with-ssl-using-resttemplate/)
3. [HttpClient with SSL](http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-ssl)

Comment: The link provided above shows two way SSL connection with spring boot which has embedded tomcat server .I need to configure two way SSL connection in a Spring bootless application with separate Tomcat 7 Server.If any links or sample code are available please update .

Comment: @brt I will let you know.

Comment: @brt I have updated 2 links. Please check and share if you got some helpful things.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to check the spring documentation to understand the basics about spring security for web services: http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/security.html. I found another tutorial (XML too), that explains how to test your web service security: https://jeromebulanadi.wordpress.com/2010/02/25/basic-spring-web-service-tutorial-from-contract-to-security/#server_security

Then if you have any specific problem when doing the implementation edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing you can do is configure a http server with SSL in front of your service. So you don't need to expose your service direct to the internet neither configure SSL in your services. And you can reuse it when you create more service.

Below I'm listing a tutorial to configure Nginx and Apache with SSL certificate and as a reverse proxy to your service.

SSL certificates:

[Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html)
[Nginx Two way SSL tutorial](http://adolgarev.blogspot.com.br/2013/12/nginx-two-way-ssl-authentication.html)
[Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html)

Reverse Proxy:
[Nginx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-http-proxying-load-balancing-buffering-and-caching)
[Apache](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension)