# How to configure two way ssl on client and server on tomcat 7 using openssl for ssl certificate generation?

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, tomcat7, mutual-authentication

I have configured th keystore  and trustore using the  solution  provided by pedrofb given in the following link
[How to configure two way SSL connection in Spring WS without using Spring boot and using separate Apache tomcat server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37248064/how-to-configure-two-way-ssl-connection-in-spring-ws-without-using-spring-boot-a/)

I have set the keystore and trustore properties for both client and server in tomcat 7. Yet, when i try to connect to server i get the error below

```
    Using SSLEngineImpl.
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
    Allow legacy hello messages: true
    Is initial handshake: true
    Is secure renegotiation: false
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
    Using SSLEngineImpl.
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
    Allow legacy hello messages: true
    Is initial handshake: true
    Is secure renegotiation: false
    http-nio-8443-exec-9, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 185
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
    *** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
    RandomCookie:  GMT: -364265602 bytes = { 151, 161, 117, 135, 49, 179, 239, 50, 221, 113, 108, 85, 152, 173, 82, 244, 120, 98, 133, 94, 72, 13, 209, 43, 60, 89, 124, 77 }
    Session ID:  {}
    Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, Unknown 0xcc:0xa9, Unknown 0xcc:0xa8, Unknown 0xcc:0x14, Unknown 0xcc:0x13, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA]
    Compression Methods:  { 0 }
    Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
    Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=localhost]
    Unsupported extension type_23, data: 
    Unsupported extension type_35, data: 
    Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withRSA, SHA512withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withECDSA
    Unsupported extension status_request, data: 01:00:00:00:00
    Unsupported extension type_18, data: 
    Unsupported extension type_16, data: 00:0c:02:68:32:08:68:74:74:70:2f:31:2e:31
    Unsupported extension type_30032, data: 
    Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
    Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {unknown curve 29, secp256r1, secp384r1}
    ***
    http-nio-8443-exec-1, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 185
    *** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
    RandomCookie:  GMT: 624575245 bytes = { 5, 128, 117, 156, 92, 134, 29, 210, 250, 146, 110, 193, 126, 10, 111%% Initialized:  [Session-27, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
    , 45, 132, 231, 235, 77, 110, 238, 35, 93, 37, 164, 168, 251 }
    Session ID:  {}
    Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, Unknown 0xcc:0xa9, Unknown 0xcc:0xa8, Unknown 0xcc:0x14, Unknown 0xcc:0x13, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA]
    Compression Methods:  { 0 }
    Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
    Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=localhost]
    Unsupported extension type_23, data: 
    Unsupported extension type_35, data: 
    Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withRSA, SHA512withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withECDSA
    Unsupported extension status_request, data: 01:00:00:00:00
    Unsupported extension type_18, data: 
    Unsupported extension type_16, data: 00:0c:02:68:32:08:68:74:74:70:2f:31:2e:31
    Unsupported extension type_30032, data: 
    Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
    Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {unknown curve 29, secp256r1, secp384r1}
    ***
    %% Initialized:  [Session-28, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
    %% Negotiating:  [Session-27, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
    *** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
    RandomCookie:  GMT: 1465167446 bytes = { 250, 227, 168, 23, 5, 88, 160, 124, 42, 177, 14, 37, 174, 160, 121, 13, 224, 215, 45, 17, 46, 117, 215, 62, 224, 31, 241, 109 }
    Session ID:  {87, 85, 174, 86, 210, 17, 84, 99, 103, 218, 211, 254, 20, 253, 117, 8, 221, 141, 57, 197, 148, 244, 184, 91, 112, 35, 41, 60, 219, 23, 171, 67}
    Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    Compression Method: 0
    Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
    ***
    Cipher suite:  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    *** Certificate chain
    chain [0] = [
    [
      Version: V1
      Subject: EMAILADDRESS=briantauro7@gmail.com, CN=localhost, OU=localhost, O=ITCOVENANT, L=Coimbatore, ST=Tamil Badu, C=IN
      Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

      Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
      modulus: 119392845705983053232381066342242552100246759562149136263179036450311601341483905580607024283403956181584600045082844169675168228225812598145033750549880051511514384914836915917053974822328749850134357052060356957993078530363525462150764881452639783264103642429891992181964954455911798298926528546562832494147
      public exponent: 65537
      Validity: [From: Mon Jun 06 22:09:30 IST 2016,
                   To: Tue Jun 06 22:09:30 IST 2017]
      Issuer: EMAILADDRESS=briantauro7@gmail.com, CN=localhost, OU=localhost, O=ITCOVENANT, L=Coimbatore, ST=Tamil Badu, C=IN
      SerialNumber: [    9f141eca db1b5892]

    ]
      Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
      Signature:
    0000: 52 80 1C 6C CF 67 1E 54   A8 D7 52 63 63 A6 5C E8  R..l.g.T..Rcc.\.
    0010: 06 AB 45 17 D9 EF A5 BA   AB 15 63 D0 8B 3E A8 F4  ..E.......c..>..
    0020: 16 DD 0A AB 64 7D 16 BD   B6 72 61 51 2C CA F3 F0  ....d....raQ,...
    0030: 72 42 AF EF 67 0C B8 F4   99 26 34 12 A6 44 67 81  rB..g....&4..Dg.
    0040: 78 79 4B 29 CC FB BC 75   32 61 54 1D C4 5F F2 BD  xyK)...u2aT.._..
    0050: 0E 5C A4 C0 A5 67 44 53   1B 0C 58 01 F0 A2 EC F3  .\...gDS..X.....
    0060: 94 F3 D9 FB D3 1A A5 BA   D9 7E 9E 49 90 10 84 7F  ...........I....
    0070: A6 7E 03 80 C0 17 2E F3   89 DE 27 31 C1 54 B5 AC  ..........'1.T..

    ]
    ***
    %% Negotiating:  [Session-28, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
    *** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
    RandomCookie:  GMT: 1465167446 bytes = { 103, 27, 241, 116, 15, 29, 188, 76, 143, 250, 43, 244, 203, 202, 45, 229, 174, 22, 232, 84, 101, 180, 15, 46, 1, 2, 102, 153 }
    Session ID:  {87, 85, 174, 86, 57, 163, 69, 204, 125, 206, 51, 246, 36, 126, 169, 3, 253, 63, 0, 8, 97, 161, 116, 83, 52, 47, 229, 6, 202, 194, 109, 25}
    Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    Compression Method: 0
    Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
    ***
    Cipher suite:  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    *** Certificate chain
    chain [0] = [
    [
      Version: V1
      Subject: EMAILADDRESS=briantauro7@gmail.com, CN=localhost, OU=localhost, O=ITCOVENANT, L=Coimbatore, ST=Tamil Badu, C=IN
      Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

      Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
      modulus: 119392845705983053232381066342242552100246759562149136263179036450311601341483905580607024283403956181584600045082844169675168228225812598145033750549880051511514384914836915917053974822328749850134357052060356957993078530363525462150764881452639783264103642429891992181964954455911798298926528546562832494147
      public exponent: 65537
      Validity: [From: Mon Jun 06 22:09:30 IST 2016,
                   To: Tue Jun 06 22:09:30 IST 2017]
      Issuer: EMAILADDRESS=briantauro7@gmail.com, CN=localhost, OU=localhost, O=ITCOVENANT, L=Coimbatore, ST=Tamil Badu, C=IN
      SerialNumber: [    9f141eca db1b5892]

    ]
      Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
      Signature:
    0000: 52 80 1C 6C CF 67 1E 54   A8 D7 52 63 63 A6 5C E8  R..l.g.T..Rcc.\.
    0010: 06 AB 45 17 D9 EF A5 BA   AB 15 63 D0 8B 3E A8 F4  ..E.......c..>..
    0020: 16 DD 0A AB 64 7D 16 BD   B6 72 61 51 2C CA F3 F0  ....d....raQ,...
    0030: 72 42 AF EF 67 0C B8 F4   99 26 34 12 A6 44 67 81  rB..g....&4..Dg.
    0040: 78 79 4B 29 CC FB BC 75   32 61 54 1D C4 5F F2 BD  xyK)...u2aT.._..
    0050: 0E 5C A4 C0 A5 67 44 53   1B 0C 58 01 F0 A2 EC F3  .\...gDS..X.....
    0060: 94 F3 D9 FB D3 1A A5 BA   D9 7E 9E 49 90 10 84 7F  ...........I....
    0070: A6 7E 03 80 C0 17 2E F3   89 DE 27 31 C1 54 B5 AC  ..........'1.T..

    ]
    ***
    *** ECDH ServerKeyExchange
    *** ECDH ServerKeyExchange
    Signature Algorithm SHA512withRSA
    Server key: Sun EC public key, 256 bits
      public x coord: 85555666343139018963533967280538968797633662983139641438682557033369225999165
      public y coord: 8427840957609862596834523195604231585301724865593291933177525359181625802444
      parameters: secp256r1 [NIST P-256, X9.62 prime256v1] (1.2.840.10045.3.1.7)
    *** CertificateRequest
    Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
    Supported Signature Algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, MD5withRSA
    Cert Authorities:
    <EMAILADDRESS=briantauro7@gmail.com, CN=localhost, OU=localhost, O=ItCovenant, L=Coimbatore, ST=Tamil Nadu, C=IN>
    <EMAILADDRESS=briantauro7@gmail.com, CN=localhost, OU=localroot, O=Root, L=Coimbatore, ST=TamilNadu, C=IN>
    *** ServerHelloDone
    Signature Algorithm SHA512withRSA
    http-nio-8443-exec-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 1336
    Server key: Sun EC public key, 256 bits
      public x coord: 84402873937186238897029201223811091119078490206065291036407576822220964455837
      public y coord: 102495088922183201760899172514801345100289489285600965229707082740951466499978
      parameters: secp256r1 [NIST P-256, X9.62 prime256v1] (1.2.840.10045.3.1.7)
    *** CertificateRequest
    Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
    Supported Signature Algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, MD5withRSA
    Cert Authorities:
    <EMAILADDRESS=briantauro7@gmail.com, CN=localhost, OU=localhost, O=ItCovenant, L=Coimbatore, ST=Tamil Nadu, C=IN>
    <EMAILADDRESS=briantauro7@gmail.com, CN=localhost, OU=localroot, O=Root, L=Coimbatore, ST=TamilNadu, C=IN>
    *** ServerHelloDone
    http-nio-8443-exec-9, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 1336
    http-nio-8443-exec-9, called closeOutbound()
    http-nio-8443-exec-9, closeOutboundInternal()
    http-nio-8443-exec-9, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
    http-nio-8443-exec-9, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
    http-nio-8443-exec-9, called closeOutbound()
    http-nio-8443-exec-9, closeOutboundInternal()
    http-nio-8443-exec-9, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
    http-nio-8443-exec-9, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
    Using SSLEngineImpl.
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
    Allow legacy hello messages: true
    Is initial handshake: true
    Is secure renegotiation: false
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
    http-nio-8443-exec-4, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 185
    *** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
    RandomCookie:  GMT: -1587396700 bytes = { 168, 137, 156, 195, 17, 132, 253, 181, 204, 114, 165, 228, 86, 231, 233, 158, 148, 15, 75, 153, 17, 24, 212, 36, 209, 134, 90, 182 }
    Session ID:  {}
    Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, Unknown 0xcc:0xa9, Unknown 0xcc:0xa8, Unknown 0xcc:0x14, Unknown 0xcc:0x13, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA]
    Compression Methods:  { 0 }
    Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
    Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=localhost]
    Unsupported extension type_23, data: 
    Unsupported extension type_35, data: 
    Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withRSA, SHA512withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withECDSA
    Unsupported extension status_request, data: 01:00:00:00:00
    Unsupported extension type_18, data: 
    Unsupported extension type_16, data: 00:0c:02:68:32:08:68:74:74:70:2f:31:2e:31
    Unsupported extension type_30032, data: 
    Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
    Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {unknown curve 29, secp256r1, secp384r1}
    ***
    %% Initialized:  [Session-29, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
    %% Negotiating:  [Session-29, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
    *** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
    RandomCookie:  GMT: 1465167446 bytes = { 225, 169, 240, 135, 216, 14, 179, 8, 242, 163, 54, 198, 242, 182, 103, 125, 233, 71, 73, 94, 94, 112, 96, 92, 230, 44, 24, 124 }
    Session ID:  {87, 85, 174, 86, 58, 130, 84, 54, 254, 224, 181, 52, 14, 113, 71, 231, 52, 58, 218, 105, 147, 197, 135, 24, 188, 193, 25, 160, 12, 186, 145, 122}
    Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    Compression Method: 0
    Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
    ***
    Cipher suite:  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    *** Certificate chain
    chain [0] = [
    [
      Version: V1
      Subject: EMAILADDRESS=briantauro7@gmail.com, CN=localhost, OU=localhost, O=ITCOVENANT, L=Coimbatore, ST=Tamil Badu, C=IN
      Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

      Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
      modulus: 119392845705983053232381066342242552100246759562149136263179036450311601341483905580607024283403956181584600045082844169675168228225812598145033750549880051511514384914836915917053974822328749850134357052060356957993078530363525462150764881452639783264103642429891992181964954455911798298926528546562832494147
      public exponent: 65537
      Validity: [From: Mon Jun 06 22:09:30 IST 2016,
                   To: Tue Jun 06 22:09:30 IST 2017]
      Issuer: EMAILADDRESS=briantauro7@gmail.com, CN=localhost, OU=localhost, O=ITCOVENANT, L=Coimbatore, ST=Tamil Badu, C=IN
      SerialNumber: [    9f141eca db1b5892]

    ]
      Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
      Signature:
    0000: 52 80 1C 6C CF 67 1E 54   A8 D7 52 63 63 A6 5C E8  R..l.g.T..Rcc.\.
    0010: 06 AB 45 17 D9 EF A5 BA   AB 15 63 D0 8B 3E A8 F4  ..E.......c..>..
    0020: 16 DD 0A AB 64 7D 16 BD   B6 72 61 51 2C CA F3 F0  ....d....raQ,...
    0030: 72 42 AF EF 67 0C B8 F4   99 26 34 12 A6 44 67 81  rB..g....&4..Dg.
    0040: 78 79 4B 29 CC FB BC 75   32 61 54 1D C4 5F F2 BD  xyK)...u2aT.._..
    0050: 0E 5C A4 C0 A5 67 44 53   1B 0C 58 01 F0 A2 EC F3  .\...gDS..X.....
    0060: 94 F3 D9 FB D3 1A A5 BA   D9 7E 9E 49 90 10 84 7F  ...........I....
    0070: A6 7E 03 80 C0 17 2E F3   89 DE 27 31 C1 54 B5 AC  ..........'1.T..

    ]
    ***
    *** ECDH ServerKeyExchange
    Signature Algorithm SHA512withRSA
    Server key: Sun EC public key, 256 bits
      public x coord: 81903135861506604845195203015394003955799288815680914864504286597024832297135
      public y coord: 106714826192296131282741266053860770585192831249415196199432006232074628631588
      parameters: secp256r1 [NIST P-256, X9.62 prime256v1] (1.2.840.10045.3.1.7)
    *** CertificateRequest
    Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
    Supported Signature Algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, MD5withRSA
    Cert Authorities:
    <EMAILADDRESS=briantauro7@gmail.com, CN=localhost, OU=localhost, O=ItCovenant, L=Coimbatore, ST=Tamil Nadu, C=IN>
    <EMAILADDRESS=briantauro7@gmail.com, CN=localhost, OU=localroot, O=Root, L=Coimbatore, ST=TamilNadu, C=IN>
    *** ServerHelloDone
    http-nio-8443-exec-4, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 1336
    http-nio-8443-exec-6, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 7
    *** Certificate chain
    <Empty>
    ***
    http-nio-8443-exec-6, fatal error: 42: null cert chain
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain
    %% Invalidated:  [Session-29, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
    http-nio-8443-exec-6, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = bad_certificate
    http-nio-8443-exec-6, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
    http-nio-8443-exec-6, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain
    http-nio-8443-exec-6, called closeOutbound()
    http-nio-8443-exec-6, closeOutboundInternal()
```

On the client side I have the following error in browser

```
Try contacting the system admin.
ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT
```

The client does not send its certificate when server requests it.

Do i have to keep `clientauth=true`, both in client and server?

```
My Server keystore contains server.pfx
My Server trustore contains client.crt and ca.crt
My Client keystore contains client.p12 client.crt ca.crt
My Client trustore contains server.crt
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally found the solution I just did not install client.p12 in the browser and hence my client was not sending its certificate to the server.Once I installed client.p12 in the browser It started working .

Answer (score 2):

The server is requesting a certificate and providing a list of trusted signers. This comes from the server's truststore. The client doesn't have a certificate signed by one of those signers in its keystore, so it cannot send a certificate.

Solution: either have the client certificate signed by one of the trusted signers, or enhance the trusted signers to include the signer of the client certificate.